# Get spark variables in oozie spark action

Tags: apache-spark, oozie, oozie-workflow

I am new to spark and oozie technologies.
I am trying to get few variables from spark  and use it in next oozie action.

In "Decision" node spark submit will be called and few processing is done and a counter variable is generated

> Eg: var counter = 8 from spark

So now I need to use this variable in next oozie action which is "take decision"
node.

```
take decision
 [Decision ][counter]
```

When I googled I was able to find few solutions

```
1. Write to hdfs
2. Wrap spark submit in shell and use <capture-output> 
(I am not able to use this as I use oozie spark action node)
```

Any other ways to do the same?

Answer (score 0):

The best approach is store the values in either HDFS (Hive) or HBase/Cassandra and your decision action read the values.

If you are wrap spark-submit with shell action, there would be problem if you submit the jobs in cluster mode because spark-submit jobs to yarn cluster and run any of the node where you cannot get the output.